# How to capture all the user navigations from an external website opened in an IFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, postmessage, cross-domain-policy

I am able to capture the user navigations from an external website opened in an IFrame into a variable and i am able to display the location in console. But i want to capture all the user navigations into an array or a text file. Please help me with this. Below is the code i have.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test page</title>
</head>

<body>

<li><a href="http://mysmallwebpage.com/" target="iframe_a">Small Page</li>

<iframe id = "frame" src="" name="iframe_a" onload ="loadImage()" width = 100% height = 100% style="border:none;"></iframe>

</body>

<script>

function loadImage() 
{

test = document.getElementById("frame").contentWindow.location; 

console.log(test);

}
</script>

</html>
```

The variable "TEST" in the script is holding the navigation link. I just want to capture all the navigations in some array or file. Please test the code using console understand my request.

Answer (score 0):

Create an empy array to hold the navigation history. You can dynamically add elements to the array using the `push` method.

Within your `loadImage` function, push the current location onto the end of the array.

```
var navigations = [];

function loadImage() 
{
    navigations.push( document.getElementById("frame").contentWindow.location );

}
```

For more information on JavaScript arrays read [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: It's an external website. That will throw a cross-origin error.

Comment: It is working but every time it is updating the 0th index of the array.

Comment: Can anyone help me doing it using postmessage() ? Heard that it helps in cross domains problems